Can't get Wi-Fi running on my MacBook Pro 2011
Suddenly my MacBook Pro 2011 does not want to launch Wi-Fi.
I've checked under "About This Mac" and found that the Wi-Fi driver is still there but if I try to add a connection in the Network System Settings WiFi doesn't show up as an alternative when I press "+"

You should probably tell us the model of the MacBook and which OS you are using. You could also tell us if you have rebooted the Mac to see if that resolved the problem.

Sounds like the Wi-Fi adapter has failed. You could try running Apple Diagnostics to confirm, but I don't know whether it can detect that kind of fault. https://support.apple.com/en-us/102550

This page may help : https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252365407?answerId=254490281022&sortBy=rank#254490281022    Maybe start by seeing if you can connect to internet in Recovery mode. Restart holding command+R and wait til the Recovery screen appears, then look for the wi-fi icon, top right.

Have you run Apple Diagnostics/Apple Hardware Test?
